# Wordpress capability_type arguments

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

I don't know how to figured out what's wrong with my code, Why Custom Post Types "Book" doesn't show on my dashboard, I logged as Admin and I use latest WordPress installed 3.4.1

Here with my code

```
function codex_custom_init() {

  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Books', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Book', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'book'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Book'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Book'),
    'new_item' => __('New Book'),
    'all_items' => __('All Books'),
    'view_item' => __('View Book'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Books'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No books found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No books found in Trash'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => __('Books')

  );

    $capabilities = array(
    'publish_posts' => 'publish_books',
    'edit_posts' => 'edit_books',
    'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_books',
    'delete_posts' => 'delete_books',
    'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_books',
    'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_books',
    'edit_post' => 'edit_book',
    'delete_post' => 'delete_book',
    'read_post' => 'read_book'
    );


  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'book',
    'capabilities' => $capabilities,
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
  ); 

  register_post_type('book',$args);

}

add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

My code is to add new custom post with custom capabilities for usage of [members plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/).

Comment: Does your role have these capabilities?

Comment: you mean adding these role on Admin?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If don’t have the capability to read or edit the post type you will not get the menu.

Comment: but My current user logged role is super admin :( so why this don't show up?

Answer (score 8):

Looks like a CPT with custom capability_type won't show up by default even as super admin.  Even manually adding the permissions for the desired user role (licensing-admin in my case) didn't make it happen - I had to manually add the capabilities for the administrator as well, then everything fell into place.

Stuck this code in my plugin activation hook and good to go.

```
$roles = array( get_role('licensing-admin'), get_role('administrator') );

foreach($roles as $role) {
  if($role) {
    $role->add_cap('edit_license');
    $role->add_cap('read_license');
    $role->add_cap('delete_license');
    $role->add_cap('edit_licenses');
    $role->add_cap('edit_others_licenses');
    $role->add_cap('publish_licenses');
    $role->add_cap('read_private_licenses');
    $role->add_cap('delete_licenses');
    $role->add_cap('delete_private_licenses');
    $role->add_cap('delete_published_licenses');
    $role->add_cap('delete_others_licenses');
    $role->add_cap('edit_private_licenses');
    $role->add_cap('edit_published_licenses');
  }
}
```

Comment: Careful, you should run this only one time, like on [register_activation_hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook), as written [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap#Description): _N.B. This setting is saved to the database (in table wp_options, field wp_user_roles), so it might be better to run this on theme/plugin activation_